# How do I best handle this pagination with asynchronous Node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

My question involves the use of asynchronous code.

Here's the relevant pseudocode:

```
function handleQueryMore(result) {
    conn.queryMore(result.nextRecordsUrl, function(err, resultMore){    
        if (err) {}
        //do stuff with result
        if (!resultMore.done){
            handleQueryMore(resultMore);
        }
    });
}

//(below code runs first when launched of course)

var conn = new jsforce.Connection({////etc
var sql = "SELECT //.......

conn.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {}
    //do stuff with result

    if (!result.done) //didn't pull all records
    {
        handleQueryMore(result);
    }               
});
```

The initial query only returns a certain maximum # of records and then handleQueryMore() is called recursively to handle each additional chunk of records.

Originally I had a single `conn.query()` in a where `(!result.done){}` loop but of course the problem there was that the `conn.query()` code runs asynchronously and doesn't get a chance to finish before the next run of the loop (resulting in an ~infinite purposeless loop).

There are 3rd party library ways to get the code to run syncronously but my guess is that there is some fundamental design paradigm that I'm not following.  The recursion works but I fear the amount of memory that could be needed if the query returns a huge # of records.

Even if I know the # of records I need to paginate through, I MUST have the `result.nextRecordsUrl` to paginate, which I can't get until each previous query is executed... so I can't just run them all at the same time.

Anyone care to weigh in on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [async.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) package.

```
function handleQueryMore(result) {

  conn.queryMore(result.nextRecordsUrl, function(err, resultMore) {
    if (err) {}
    //do stuff with result
    else {
      async.each(result.data, function(individualData, callback) {
        // do some async task
        callback(); // to tell that this is completed
        //callback(err); if there is any error while processing data
      }, function(error) {
        if (!error) {
          if (!result.done) //didn't pull all records
          {
            handleQueryMore(result);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });


}



var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ ////etc
  var sql = "SELECT //.......

  conn.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {} else {
      async.each(result.data, function(individualData, callback) {
        // do some async task
        callback(); // to tell that this is completed
        //callback(err); if there is any error while processing data
      }, function(error) {
        if (!error) {
          if (!result.done) //didn't pull all records
          {
            handleQueryMore(result);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your concise and relevant answer!  I'll try this tomorrow and follow up.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it that that way at all.  It is horribly inefficient as you get bigger data sets.   Instead I'd take in querystring parameters that indicate the record index I want to start at and the count to return.  All databases have an equivalent of skip and take (e.g. if you're using the jsforce method chain API you can do .skip(5).take(10) to return records 6 - 16 in a set).  This simplifies your code a lot and reduces risk by making each request independent of others.

Also, I notice the comment `//(below code runs first when launched of course)`, but that's also not a great idea.  You ideally want to query the db on demand, not on app start. That also might be why you're running into the challenges that you're having.

Comment: This is redux code; the "real" code has a "main" that calls the code in question.  I'll check out the presence of skip/take when I get back to my workstation

Comment: That's not my point, Juan, my point is that the query in most cases should happen on client request, unless it's information which your application is caching and rarely changes.

Comment: I now get your point.  This though is a batch process that will be triggered by a scheduler so there are no clients involved.

Comment: It might be useful if you posted relevant parts of your actual code and a better description of what you're trying to do.  It is hard to answer correctly based on pseudocode and no objective.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I shouldn't have called it pseudocode, other than the SQL statement and a lack of 'require' statements, the code is totally runnable and includes only the parts relevant to my question.  I'm sorry I didn't explicitly mention that it wasn't client driven; I'm new to Node.js and didn't consider that this would be the assumption.     That said, it does appear that you're correct in saying jsforce does support skip/take though it seems to require query method chaining, which is fine, but will require reworking the queries.  I'll check this out.  Thank you!

Comment: So, it's not so much a node thing as it is a database thing.  The vast majority of apps that use data in the back end have some client (even if that client is an automated process) that needs the data to perform some operation. You generally don't want to load all the data from that back end into the consuming application at once as that's inefficient and possibly could lead to consistency issues with the data. So it's better to get a chunk, do whatever you need with it, then get the next chunk, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

## Hii if u are using mongo db then try this..

```
   user.aggregate({ $match: { status: true, type: req.query.type } },
        { "$skip": (skipValue) }, { "$limit": limitValue },
        (err, data) => {
//Code
})
```